# Efficiently Loading a Large Time Series Dataset into KairosDB

Tags: python, database, time-series, loading, kairosdb

I am trying to load 100 billion multi-dimensional time series datapoints into KairosDB from a CSV file with the following format:

> timestamp value_1 value_2 .... value_n

I tried to find a fast loading method on the [official documentation](https://kairosdb.github.io/docs/PushingData.html) and here's how I am currently doing the insertion (my codebase is in Python):

```
f = open(args.file, "r")
# Insert
i = 0
with tqdm(total=int(rows)) as pbar:
    while i < len(range(rows)):   
        data = []
        batch_size = 65000 / column
        while i < len(range(rows)) and batch_size > 0:
            batch_size -= 1
            # print(batch_size)
            i += 1
            values = f.readline()[:-1].split(" ")
            t = (get_datetime(values[0])[0] - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds() * 1000
            t = int(t)
            for j in range(column):
                    data.append({
                            "name": "master.data",
                            "datapoints": [[t, values[j + 1]]],
                            "tags": {
                                    "dim": "dim" + str(j)
                            }
                    })    
        r = requests.post("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/datapoints", data = json.dumps(data))
        pbar.update(65000 / column)
pbar.close()
```

As the code above shows, my code is reading the dataset CSV file and preparing batches of 65000 data points, then sending the datapoints using `requests.post`.

However, this method is not very efficient. In fact, I am trying to load 100 billion data points and this is taking way longer than expected, loading only 3 Million rows with 100 columns each has been running for 29 hours and still has 991 hours to finish!!!!

[image]

I am certain there is a better way to load the dataset into KairosDB. Any suggestions for faster data loading?